# How to prevent text converting into image when exporting as HTML in firework

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I am an architect and I want to design my basic website with minimum graphics. I'm using coreldraw, but it's more related to print (hardcopies) and it's not as "smart" compared to the adobe software.

So, for web design, I started to learn Fireworks and after some practice, I was able to design web graphics. But the main problem is that, when that page is exported into html format, all text is converted into image.

Comment: Generally you just hide unwanted items before saving.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously fireworks will export the text in the form of a graphic. If you don't want it to be an image, you must manually add it in the HTML. You could use an IDE such as dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep it "simple", you shouldn't be trying to create The Whole Website in Fireworks...

Converting your design to html even for a simple site is not gonna work out for you right now. ..

I don't want to discourage you since you already took the initiative to start learning fireworks, never a bad idea to learn something new. But you might just want to go with a template for website (nowadays you can even install wordpress using your webhost). Using a CMS like wordpress would be your best bet.

So, go with a templated site and once you have the framework then you can use your newly learnt talent and design some banners/images for your website.